# Haskell returning variable not in scope error

Tags: haskell, ghci

I have the following Haskell script,

```
right :: Int -> [(Int,Int,Int)]
right n = [(a,b,c) | [1..n] <- a, [a..n] <- b, [b..n] <- c, a*a + b*b == c*c]
```

When I compile the script in ghci and enter "right 10" I get an error saying
"* Variable not in scope: right :: Integer -> t"

To be clear I first enter ":l init" (file is 'init.hs') and then I try to call the function.

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5):

I think you haven't actually compiled your script in ghci yet. When I try, I get an error message:

```
Parse error in pattern: [1 .. n]
Possibly caused by a missing 'do'?
```

This is because you've got the order of things to `<-` backwards.

```
right n = [(a,b,c) | a <- [1..n], b <- [a..n], c <- [b..n], a*a + b*b == c*c]
```

Comment: Thanks very much. I'm rather tired, can't believe I missed something so stupid : |